# How to I want to filter the couchDB using the mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I created a view.

map

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.country, 1);
}
```

reduce(Raw view)

```
function(key, values) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

result

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":120081}
]}
```

I want to get these results.(example)

```
{"rows":[
{"key":US,"value":2135}
{"key":CN,"value":556}
{"key":EN,"value":5414}
]}
```

like this....

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group_level=1` when you query.